# How can I replicate rolling.sum() in Pandas V17

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I am trying to calculate the rolling 3 days sum for the data below:

```
Date        Qty
01/01/2019  4.15
02/01/2019  12.39
03/01/2019  14.15
04/01/2019  12.15
05/01/2019  3.26
06/01/2019  6.23
07/01/2019  15.89
08/01/2019  5.55
09/01/2019  12.49
10/01/2019  9.4
11/01/2019  9.11
12/01/2019  9.18
13/01/2019  13.45
14/01/2019  4.52
```

I tried:

```
data['Rolling_3_day'] = data['Qty'].rolling(3).sum()
```

But i got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'rolling'
```

I think the issue is that .rolling is added for Pandas V18 but I had Pandas V17. But I CAN NOT update pandas now.
Is there a way i can calculate rolling sum using V17?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a small window, you can `shift`:

```
df['rolling_3d'] = np.sum([df['Qty'].shift(i) for i in range(3)], axis=0)
```

Comment: Works exactly, Thank you, Quang!